TypeError: TypeError: navigation.navigate is not a function (it is undefined)
I am repeatedly getting the same error TypeError: navigation.navigate is not a function (it is undefined), and I'm not sure why. I am learning React Native, and trying to use react-navigation to navigate between pages.
const MenuButtonGroup = ({navigation}) => { //Creates several MenuButtons for each item in an object
return (
    <View>
        {Object.keys(Houses).map((key) => (
            <MenuButton text={key} navigation={navigation}/>
        ))}
    </View>
); 
};

The error is happening on line 83 aka <MenuButton text={key} navigation={navigation}/>. I have two .tsx files, called "houses.tsx" and "rooms.tsx". The snippet above is from "houses.tsx" which is my main file.
Currently I have two screens, which are also defined in "houses.tsx":
const App = () => {
return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="HouseMenu">
            <Stack.Screen name="HouseMenu" component={HouseMenu} />
            <Stack.Screen name="RoomsMenu" component={rooms} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
);
}

when I print navigation inside MenuButtonGroup, it comes out as "Rooms", which is expected.

I also tried creating a plain ol' button to navigate to "Rooms", and it gave the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined"

There are no navigation.navigate in the code you provided

And can you add the full error message with the failing component?
